# How do I stop the array from showing all the null values in my loop?

Tags: java

so I'm a beginner at this programming stuff and I'm making a basic Contact Manager for practice. I have the add contact method perfect and I was just trying to figure out how to make it so that if there is no value in my array after a certain point. It won't print that line. Basically trying to stop the loop after the last known object in the array. My code i have for this is.

```
public static void viewAllContacts(){



    for (x = 0; x < 100; x++){


        System.out.println("Full name: " +name[x]);
        System.out.println("Number: " +number[x]);
        System.out.println("E-mail Address: " +email[x]);
        System.out.println("Home Address: " +address[x]);
        System.out.println("Birthday: " +birthday[x]);
        System.out.println("Nickname: " +nickname[x]);
        System.out.println(" "); //space so that way the contact list is a bit prettier 

    }
}
```

Comment: I would use a foreach. It will only write the actual items, not 100 or a generic number.

Comment: `for (x = 0; x < 100 && name[x] != null; x++)` when you know that name is like a primary key.

Comment: And it would be much easier to use some `ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();` where contact is a class with name, number, email....

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the the values in each of the array is synchronized (same number of elements) then simply

```
for (x = 0; x < 100; x++){

    if (name[x]  == null)
       break;
```

of course you could also use a `field` to hold the max number of elements and then only loop until this number.

```
for (x = 0; x < maxNumberOfElements; x++){
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do two things:

The first is to create a class to keep all your information instead of keeping it in separate arrays - keeping track of one array per attribute is really cumbersome.

Person.java:

```
public class Person {
    // Attributes
    private String name;
    private String number;
    private String email;
    private String address;
    private String birthday;
    private String nickname;

    // Constructor
    public Person(String name, String number, String email, String address,
            String birthday, String nickname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
        this.email = email;
        this.address = address;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }

    // Getters and setters

    public String getName() {
          return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    // And so on for all attributes
}
```

Then you should store your `Person` objects in an [`ArrayList`](https://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F8%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjava%2Futil%2FArrayList.html&ei=iDJ2VcyVGcL68QXt-IOQCA&usg=AFQjCNFKE9Oi482rB8pNSM0qp6xiZZrKbw&sig2=U81GP3OLL5Oeh7D9ZgjOpA&bvm=bv.95039771,d.dGc) so the size of the list matches how many `Person` objects you have. You can then use a foreach loop to iterate over the list:

```
ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

persons.add(new Person("John Doe", "555-12345", "john@doe.com", "Fake Street 999",
        "1970-01-01", "Johnny"));
persons.add(new Person("Jane Doe", "555-12345", "jane@doe.com", "Fake Street 999",
        "1999-12-12", "Janey"));

for(Person person : persons) {
    System.out.println("Full name: " + person.getName());
    System.out.println("Number: " + person.getNumber());
    System.out.println("E-mail Address: " + person.getEmail());
    System.out.println("Home Address: " + person.getAddress());
    System.out.println("Birthday: " + person.getBirthday());
    System.out.println("Nickname: " + person.getNickname());
    System.out.println(); // Empty line
}
```

Comment: Another big advantage doing it like this is it also works nicely if some properties are `null`.

Comment: Quite long, and might be slow, but as @maraca said, it works well with `null` properties.

Comment: So using this way makes it so I can manually add the persons name and information into the code itself, how do I still get the users input?

Comment: No, that is just to provide an example. You would still input details as you're doing right now but instead of putting each attribute in it's own array you create a Person object and put the attributes in there.

Answer (score 0):

As an additional answer, you could also `continue` if `null` instead of break. 
If there are elements in the array that do not point to anything and some of the elements after that, do point to values, this may be useful:

```
for (x = 0; x < 100; x++){
    if (name[x] == null)
        continue;
}
```

Comment: The nice thing about that is that it skips all of the `null` values, and includes any other non-`null` values.